# Sql query for Postgresql database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 4 columns in a table.

```
A <date>
B <boolean>
C <boolean>
D <numeric>
```

I want result from database in datewise where :

if B true THEN Sum of D for that day
if C true THEN Sum of D

```
  A         B   C    D
11/1/2014   T       50
11/1/2014   T       40
11/1/2014       T   20
12/1/2014   T       60
12/1/2014   T       70
13/1/2014       T   55
13/1/2014       T   20
14/1/2014       T   10
14/1/2014   T       18
```

Desired Result

```
A            E   F
11/1/2014   90  20
12/1/2014   130 0
13/1/2014       75
14/1/2014   18  10
```

Comment: Can you at least show what you have attempted thus far?

Comment: Please, use the term columns, not fields.

Comment: What if every row on the same date has a differenct value on B and C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select a, 
       sum(case when b then d end) as e,
       sum(case when c then d end) as f
group by a;
```

If you are using Postgres 9.4 you can make this a bit more readable by using a filtered aggregate

```
select a, 
       sum(d) filter (b) as e,
       sum(d) filter (c) as f
group by a;
```